# Visual Studio можно ли у существующего проекта получить диаграмму классов?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Здравствуйте знатоки. Имеется большой проект реализованный в среде Visual Studio 2013(С#, Asp.net,Ms SQL). Проект достаточно большой, можно как нибудь получить диаграмму классов чтобы хорошенько вникнуть в структуру? и как это сделать? Если еще какие нибудь способы посоветуете было бы здорово. 
Спасибо заранее

Comment: возможно подойдет вариант нажатия кнопки `Show on Code Map` на вкладке `Solution Explorer` в `Visual Studio`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UML-диаграммы выпили из поставки студии, последний раз было в 2010-ой, если не ошибаюсь. Говорили, что не пользуется функция популярностью. Ищите сторонние инструменты.